# Extension of morphism to its projective closure

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine variety and $Y$ be a projective variety over a field $k$ and $\phi: X \to Y$ is a morphism between varieties. Let $\bar{X}$ be the projective closure of $X$ ($\bar{X}$ is obtained as follows: if $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$, embed $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$, then $\bar{X}$ is closure of $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$). Then is it always possible to extend $\phi$ from $\bar{X} \to Y$.
I think we can extend $\phi$ by homogenizing the polynomials defining $\phi$. But I cannot show whether the points of infinity of $X$ are zeros of homogenization of $\phi$. I think projective closure of an affine variety has some universal property via this, any such morphism to projective variety has the unique extension (like compactification of a topological space). We can assume the underlying field is algebraically closed. May be I am completety wrong. Please explain this.

Comment: Imagine $X$ is two parallel lines in $\mathbb{A}^2$ so $\bar X$ is two lines meeting at a point. If $\phi$ is a morphism (to $\mathbb{P}^1$, say) taking one value on one line and another on the other, it cannot be extended to $\bar X$.

Comment: Let $X := \mathbf{A}^2 - \{(0,0)\}$ and $Y := \mathbf{P}^1$ and consider the map $(x,y) \mapsto [x:y]$. The projective closure of $X$ is $\mathbf{P}^2$ and so this map cannot extend: By Bezout's theorem, there is no non-constant morphism from $\mathbf{P}^2$ to $\mathbf{P}^1$.

Comment: But $\mathbb{A}^2-{(0,0)}$ is not an affine variety. I am looking for example of an affine variety.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen union of two parallel lines is not irreducible. I am looking for an example of affine variety in particular irreducible.

Comment: Take the map $\mathbb{A}^2\to\mathbb{P}^2$, given by $(x,xy,1)$, where $x,y$ are co-ordinates of $\mathbb{A}^2$. This is dominant and contracts the line $x=0$ to a point. This can not be extended to $\mathbb{P}^2$, a projective closure of $\mathbb{A}^2$, since any dominant morphism from $\mathbb{P}^2$ to itself is finite.

Comment: You can modify @DavidBenjaminLim's example as follows: take $X=\mathbb{A}^2$, $\overline{X}=\mathbb{P}^2$, $Y=\mathbb{P}^1$, $\phi=$ any nonconstant morphism, e.g. $(x,y)\mapsto[x:1]$.

Comment: If you assume your varieties to be irreducible, you should state so. Anyway, it's easy to correct the example: take the usual nodal cubic curve $\bar X$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$, choose the line at infinity so that $X := \bar X \cap \mathbb{A}^2$ is the smooth part, let $Y$ be the normalization of $\bar X$ and $\phi\colon X\to Y$ be the identity on the smooth part: then you can't extend $\phi$ to $\bar X$.

Comment: And if you don't like the explanation with “the usual nodal cubic” etc., I can be explicit: take $X$ to be $\{1+v-u^2 v = 0\}$ in the affine plane with coordinates $(u,v)$ and $\phi\colon X\to \mathbb{P}^1$ takes $(u,v)$ to $(1:u)$. Just looking at the graph should make it obvious that $\phi$ won't extend to the (singular) point at infinity of $\bar X$.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Thanks!

Comment: @BimanRoy Sorry I missed out the affine part. At any rate, as Laurent Moret-Bailly said my example is easily modified to get an affine one.

Comment: As pointed out, the answer is no.  However, I think you can always compactify the affine variety in such a way that the map you want exists.  That latter basically follows by "resolving the indeterminacy" of the map (see Hartshorne, II, end of section 7 iirc).  Ie, you certainly get a rational map $\overline{X} \dashrightarrow Y$.  Now resolve the indeterminacy to get $X' \to Y$ ($X'$ is projective), finally, with a little work, I think one can always make $X$ standard affine open in $X'$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a family of counterexamples can be constructed in the following way. Note that my notation is slightly different from yours.

Start with a smooth, minimal projective surface $X$, and let $\tilde{X}$ be the blow-up of $X$ at a point $p \in X$. If $E$ is the exceptional divisor, $H$ is an ample divisor on $\tilde{X}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is big enough, a general divisor $D \in |nH| $ is smooth and irreducible and $\tilde{D}=D + E$ is ample, too.

Then $\tilde{X}-\tilde{D}$ is an affine variety, isomorphic to an affine subvariety $X^{0} \subset X$. Moreover, composing the isomorphism $X^{0} \to \tilde{X}-\tilde{D}$ with the inclusion $\tilde{X}-\tilde{D} \to \tilde{X}$, we get a birational morphism $\phi \colon X^{0} \to \tilde{X}$.

Such a morphism cannot be extended to a birational morphism $f \colon X \to   \tilde{X}$. In fact, by minimality of $X$ such an extension would be an isomorphism, a contradiction since $X$ and $\tilde{X}$ have different Picard numbers.